# How to combine multi field distinct in elasticsearch

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

**for example, I have six documents here there:**

- 1. {"task_id": 1, "frame": 1, "job_id": 1},
- 2. {"task_id": 1, "frame": 1, "job_id": 1},
- 3. {"task_id": 1, "frame": 1, "job_id": 3},
- 4. {"task_id": 2, "frame": 1, "job_id": 2},
- 5. {"task_id": 2, "frame": 1, "job_id": 3},
- 6. {"task_id": 3, "frame": 1, "job_id": 3},

*I want get the count of documents with the same task_id.*

**the expect result must be (the key is "task_id")**:

```
[
  {"key": 1, "doc_count": 2},  
  {"key": 2,  "doc_count":2},  
  {"key": 3, "doc_count":1}
]
```

**Note**:the first document and the second document all value is same, so it only calculate once.

So how can I write query in elasticsearch? I can easy write it in SQL, but I puzzled in Elasticsearch.

**my mysql query is**:

```
select tmp.task_id, count(*) from (select distinct task_id,frame,job_id from mytable) as tmp group by tmp.task_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) on the `task_id` + `frame` + `job_id` fields (using a `script`), and you'll get the `doc_count` you are expecting.

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/your_index/_search -d '{
    "size" 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "tasks" : {
            "terms" : { "script" : "[doc.task_id.value, doc.frame.value, doc.job_id.value].join(',')" }
        }
    }
}'
```

Note that in order to run this, you need to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting).

Comment: just curious whether it will return distinct count, because question says distinct count

Comment: I see what you mean, the distinct is on several fields. Updated answer

Comment: sorry, I can't use it to get the expecting result. It   give me the result like this:    {
          "key": "1,1,1",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "1,1,3",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "2,1,2",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "2,1,3",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "3,1,3",
          "doc_count": 1
        }.

Comment: It close to my expecting, I need use this result and add them up by task_id。but how can I direct get my expecting result